# Android Preferences - On/Off Switch Icons Reset When Scrolled Offscreen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm writing an android app in eclipse. In my preferences / settings screen I have on/off switch icons at the top. If I scroll to the bottom of the settings screen and scroll back to the top to see the switches again, they have changed from off to on, or on to off. They are random. Not all switches change at the same time. Sometimes its a few, sometimes all do it.

Mostly it seems that they switch from off to on, but sometimes its the reverse. Has anyone seen this before? Can anyone help with this issue? I will post code if need be when I get to a PC. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is my code.  This is my main activity, which is the options menu code.  This main activity is a ViewPager with multiple fragments.  More than half way down you see where i call settings activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.refresh:
        item.setActionView(R.layout.ab_loading);
        item.expandActionView();

        if (currentTab == 0 && mMarketFragment != null && mMarketFragment.isAdded()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "MarketFrag isnt null and its added");

            Loader loader = mMarketFragment.getLoaderManager().getLoader(2); 
            if ( loader != null && !loader.isReset() ) { 
                mMarketFragment.getLoaderManager().restartLoader(2, null, mMarketFragment); 
                mMarketFragment.getLoaderManager().restartLoader(3, null, mMarketFragment); 
                mMarketFragment.getLoaderManager().restartLoader(4, null, mMarketFragment);
            } else {
                mMarketFragment.getLoaderManager().initLoader(2, null, mMarketFragment);
                mMarketFragment.getLoaderManager().initLoader(3, null, mMarketFragment);
                mMarketFragment.getLoaderManager().initLoader(4, null, mMarketFragment);
            }
        }             
        else if (currentTab == 1 && mPortfolioFragment != null && mPortfolioFragment.isAdded()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "PortfolioFrag isnt null and is added");
            Loader loader2 = mPortfolioFragment.getLoaderManager().getLoader(-1); 
            if ( loader2 != null && !loader2.isReset() ) { 
                mPortfolioFragment.getLoaderManager().restartLoader(-1, null, mPortfolioFragment); 
            } else {
                mPortfolioFragment.getLoaderManager().initLoader(-1, null, mPortfolioFragment);
            }
            mPortfolioFragment.getLoaderManager().getLoader(-1).forceLoad();
        }
        else if (currentTab == 2 && mNewsFragment != null) {
            mNewsFragment.refresh();
        }
        else if (currentTab == 3 && mTwitterFragment != null) {
            mTwitterFragment.refresh();
        }

        return true;

    case R.id.dark:
        MainStocksICSActivity.THEME = R.style.DefaultTheme;
        saveTheme(R.style.DefaultTheme);
        return true;
    case R.id.light:
        MainStocksICSActivity.THEME = R.style.LightTheme;
        saveTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        return true;
    case R.id.lightDark:
        MainStocksICSActivity.THEME = R.style.LightDarkTheme;
        saveTheme(R.style.LightDarkTheme);
        return true;
    case R.id.settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MarketActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        Log.v(TAG, "settings call");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_SETTINGS);
        return true;        
    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
       super.onBackPressed();
       return true;
    case R.id.stocksearch:
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MarketActivity.this, StockSearchActivity.class);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        Log.v(TAG, "stock search call");
        startActivityForResult(intent, MENU_STOCK_ADDTICKER);
        return true;


    default:
        return true;
    }        
}
```

Here is my settings activity and fragment.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
            new PrefsFragment()).commit();
}


public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

}

And here is my settings XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:key="using_categories_in_root_screen"
android:title="SETTINGS"
android:summary="Test">

<PreferenceCategory 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="settings_topic_title"
    android:title="GENERAL">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="settings_rss_feed_save"
        android:title="@string/settings_saving_policy_title"
        android:switchTextOn = "YES"
        android:switchTextOff = "NO"
        android:summary="@string/settings_saving_policy_summary" />

    <!--CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="settings_auto_sync"
        android:title="@string/settings_sync_title"
        android:summary="@string/settings_sync_summary" /-->


    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="settings_use_external_browser"
            android:title="Use external browser"
            android:summary="User external browser when displaying web content for stocks and news"
            android:switchTextOn = "YES"
            android:switchTextOff = "NO"
            android:defaultValue="false" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="invert_graph"
    android:title="Graph Color">

    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="settings_invert_graph"
            android:title="Invert Graph with Theme"
            android:summary="Whether to invert the graph color wiht the selected theme."
            android:switchTextOn = "Yes"
            android:switchTextOff = "No"
            android:defaultValue="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Quotes Source">

    <EditTextPreference
            android:key="edittext_preference"
            android:title="@string/title_edittext_preference"
            android:summary="@string/summary_edittext_preference"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_edittext_preference" />

    <ListPreference
            android:key="stock_data_source"
            android:title="Quote Data Source"
            android:summary="Select Yahoo or Google for quotes"
            android:entries="@array/stock_data_source_options"
            android:entryValues="@array/stock_data_source"
            android:defaultValue="yahoo_data"
            android:dialogTitle="Select the quote source" />
    <ListPreference
            android:key="chart_data_source"
            android:title="Chart Data Source"
            android:summary="Set the Small Chart (non-trendline is better for clearer small text)"
            android:entries="@array/chart_data_source_options"
            android:entryValues="@array/chart_data_source"
            android:defaultValue="yahoo_chart_with_trendlines"
            android:dialogTitle="Select the chart source" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="News Options">

    <!-- This PreferenceScreen tag serves as a screen break (similar to page break
         in word processing). Like for other preference types, we assign a key
         here so it is able to save and restore its instance state. -->
    <PreferenceScreen
            android:key="subscriptions_screen"
            android:title="Yahoo News Categories"
            android:summary="Select which categories to display in news general screen">

        <!-- You can place more preferences here that will be shown on the next screen. -->

        <PreferenceCategory 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:key="subscriptions_news"
            android:title="@string/title_newstopic">
            <SwitchPreference
                    android:key="usmarkets"
                    android:title="@string/title_usmarkets"
                    android:summary="Something"
                    android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                    android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                     />
            <SwitchPreference
                    android:key="mostpopular"
                    android:title="@string/title_mostpopular"
                    android:summary="Test"
                    android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                    android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                     />
            <SwitchPreference
                    android:key="investingstrategies"
                    android:title="@string/title_investingstrategies"
                    android:summary="four"
                    android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                    android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                     />
            <SwitchPreference
                    android:key="taxes"
                    android:title="@string/title_taxes"
                    android:summary="funtimes"
                    android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                    android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                     />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:key="subscription_basicmaterials"
            android:title="@string/title_basicmaterials">

            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="OilGasRefiningMarketing"
                android:title="@string/title_OilGasRefiningMarketing"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="Gold"
                android:title="@string/title_Gold"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="Silver"
                android:title="@string/title_Silver"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="SteelIron"
                android:title="@string/title_SteelIron"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="Synthetics"
                android:title="@string/title_Synthetics"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:key="subscription_financial"
            android:title="@string/title_financial">
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="AssetManagement"
                android:title="@string/title_AssetManagement"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="RealEstateDevelopment"
                android:title="@string/title_RealEstateDevelopment"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="CreditServices"
                android:title="@string/title_CreditServices"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="LifeInsurance"
                android:title="@string/title_LifeInsurance"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="SavingsLoans"
                android:title="@string/title_SavingsLoans"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:key="subscription_healthcare"
            android:title="@string/title_healthcare">
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="HealthCarePlans"
                android:title="@string/title_HealthCarePlans"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="Hospitals"
                android:title="@string/title_Hospitals"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="MedicalInstrumentsSupplies"
                android:title="@string/title_MedicalInstrumentsSupplies"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:key="subscription_technology"
            android:title="@string/title_technology">
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="ApplicationSoftware"
                android:title="@string/title_ApplicationSoftware"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="HealthcareInformationServices"
                android:title="@string/title_HealthcareInformationServices"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="InternetSoftwareServices"
                android:title="@string/title_InternetSoftwareServices"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="WirelessCommunications"
                android:title="@string/title_WirelessCommunications"
                android:switchTextOn = "YES"
                android:switchTextOff = "NO"
                 />
        </PreferenceCategory>

    </PreferenceScreen>
    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="google_news"
            android:title="Google News"
            android:summary="Whether to include Google News"
            android:switchTextOn = "YES"
            android:switchTextOff = "NO"
            android:defaultValue="false" />     
    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="foxbusiness_news"
            android:title="Fox Business News"
            android:summary="Whether to include Fox Business News"
            android:switchTextOn = "YES"
            android:switchTextOff = "NO"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="bloggingstocks_news"
            android:title="Blogging Stocks News"
            android:summary="Whether to include BloggingStocks News"
            android:switchTextOn = "YES"
            android:switchTextOff = "NO"
            android:defaultValue="false" /> 
    <SwitchPreference
            android:key="wsj_news"
            android:title="Wall St Journal Market News"
            android:summary="Whether to include WSJ News"
            android:switchTextOn = "YES"
            android:switchTextOff = "NO"
            android:defaultValue="false" /> 
</PreferenceCategory>
```

ALL of the switches don't stick and reset when they go off screen.  Notice my settings has a few screens, one uses list preference, and the main one at the top does not.  Yet all switches don't stick.  Am i missing something stupid?  Please help if i overlooked something.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you use ListView for your settings page?

Comment: No I am using the standard addPreferencesFromResource and preference XML file as the android docs show. It does seem like a list adapter is recycling the views off screen. But no, I'm not using any list view or custom settings setup. Its regular settings per the docs. I'll post my code in a minute.

Comment: I have edited my first post/question and added my relevant code.  Thanks!